# Image Magic - different output to pipe vs file

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

ImageMagick:
Why is output different for

```
convert image.png out.pdf
```

and

```
convert image.png pdf:- > out.pdf
```

The first output is 55kb and second output is 56kb.

Java PDFBox throws an error on pdf from the pipe/output redirect.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Edit 1:
Mac OS 10.12.3 image magick convert Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-2 Q16 x86_64 2017-03-11

There is difference at the end of the file and those number actually appear in PDFBox exception:

redirected output:

```
xref
0 18
0000000000 65535 f 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
18446744073709551615 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 18
/Info 17 0 R
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<312b2917944e1f1391c7e989f380aafcbed384ae70effb7823f655ea1d84ad66> <312b2917944e1f1391c7e989f380aafcbed384ae70effb7823f655ea1d84ad66>]
>>
startxref
10
%%EOF
```

vs directly saved to a file:

```
xref
0 18
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000010 00000 n 
0000000059 00000 n 
0000000118 00000 n 
0000000312 00000 n 
0000000402 00000 n 
0000000420 00000 n 
0000000458 00000 n 
0000000479 00000 n 
0000051784 00000 n 
0000051805 00000 n 
0000051833 00000 n 
0000054546 00000 n 
0000054567 00000 n 
0000054628 00000 n 
0000054646 00000 n 
0000054668 00000 n 
0000054686 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 18
/Info 17 0 R
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<312b2917944e1f1391c7e989f380aafcbed384ae70effb7823f655ea1d84ad66> <312b2917944e1f1391c7e989f380aafcbed384ae70effb7823f655ea1d84ad66>]
>>
startxref
54877
%%EOF
```

Comment: It would be interesting to test this with ghostscript (which ImageMagick uses IIRC), i.e. does GS fail too when using stdout on a mac? If yes, submit bug report to them.

Answer (score 0):

Both commands should work fine, and do so on my machine. I can only suggest you inspect the first few lines of each and compare them to see if there is something extra in the redirected one.

```
convert image.png a.pdf

convert image.png pdf:- > b.pdf

head a.pdf

head b.pdf
```

Comment: Updated original post. There is a difference in those files, but I have no idea what is it caused by.

Comment: What OS do you have? I do have Mac OS 10.12.3 image magick convert Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-2 Q16 x86_64 2017-03-11

Answer (score 0):

Mark Setchell:

```
convert image.png pdf:- > output.pdf
convert image.png file.pdf
ls -la
18050 Apr 27 15:25 image.png
44650 Apr 28 11:51 file.pdf
44803 Apr 28 11:51 output.pdf
```

java -jar "/private/var/www/nodeapp-template/node_modules/easy-pdf-merge/jar/pdfbox.jar" PDFMerger output.pdf output.pdf final-output.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "18446744073709551615"
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseXrefTable(COSParser.java:2012)

head has same output, no diff, but tail has diff.

Note: on debian works, on my macbook not working :(
btw debian create different files (size 55347 55328), but java PDFMerger pass.